# Error in Email Action "html body data value too large"

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I am getting this error "html body data value too large" when I am replying to customer's mail which includes any table.
So basically I am getting this error because of that table.

If anyone have any solution please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to inspect the raw html of that table, for example running a `SELECT HtmlBody, TextBody FROM EmailMessage WHERE Id = '...'`. I suspect the client sent you something nasty generated by MS Outlook, with lots of hidden styles, useless `<span>`s etc.

You could try to foward it to some email client and reply only to plaintext version? Or copy the content to new email, chances are useless stuff will be dropped. Or start a [draft messsage](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=case_interaction_enabling_email_drafts.htm&type=5), use a script or data loader to edit the content and cut the rubbish out.